# When is semicolon mandatory in scala?

Tags: scala, syntax, semicolon-inference

I am learning how to program in Scala and was being told that semicolon is optional in Scala. So with that in mind, I tried with the following nested block of code which does not have semi colon. However, it throws an error in the Scala REPL

```
scala> { val a = 1
 | {val b = a * 2
 | {val c = b + 4
 | c}
 | }
 | }
<console>:17: error: Int(1) does not take parameters
   {val b = a * 2
```

And the sample with semi colon worked perfectly fine.

```
scala> { val a = 1;
 | { val b = a*2;
 | { val c = b+4; c}
 | }
 | }
res22: Int = 6
```

Therefore it seems to me that semi colon is not really optional and is mandatory in some situations. May I ask in what situation the semi colon is mandatory?

Comment: @Bergi, I doubt so https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/204278/should-i-use-semicolons-to-delimit-scala-statements

Comment: @Bergi What are you talking about? Here is [a typical piece of Scala code](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/mutable/HashMap.scala). It contains three semicolons per 177 lines, exactly in the situation where multiple expressions are wrapped in `{}` (for no good reason, in this case, all those semicolons could be omitted, but the author was too lazy to type a line break, apparently).

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, you mean the result of my error is due to missing line break?

Comment: Most of the time (I'd estimate around 99.5% or so), the semicolon is mandatory only when the expression without the semicolon doesn't make any sense. For example, `{val b = a * 2 { val c = b + 4 ; c }}` does not make any sense, because `2` does not have a method `apply` that could take the block `{ val c = b + 4; c }` as argument. Contrast it to e.g. `Future` companion object, where you can write `Future { val c = b + 4; c }` without problems, because unlike `2`, the object `Future` *does provide* an appropriate `apply` method.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, Thanks for the explanation. I thought that putting the statements on multiple lines will be suffice in this case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll try to extract the essence from your example.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
{ val x = 1 { val y = 2 } }
```

To the compiler, it looks like syntactic sugar for

```
{ val x = 1.apply({ val y = 2 }) }
```

But the object `1` does not have an `apply` method that takes blocks, therefore the compiler produces an error:

> error: Int(1) does not take parameters
>
> ```
>   { val x = 1 { val y = 2 } }
>               ^
> ```

Contrast this to

```
object I { def apply(a: => Any): Unit = () }
{ val x = I { val y = 2 } }
```

This works, because `I` now *does* have an `apply` method.

To make the differentiation between these two cases a little bit easier, the compiler requires a semicolon in the first case.

Now one might wonder why a line break between `val x = 1` and the `{` is not converted into an inferred semicolon. I think the relevant quote from the spec would be this ([1.2 Newline Characters](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/01-lexical-syntax.html#newline-characters)) (most parts of enumerations omitted (`[...]`), emphasis mine):

> The Scala grammar [...] contains productions where
>   optional `nl` tokens, but not semicolons, are accepted. This has the
>   effect that a **newline in one of these positions does not terminate an
>   expression or statement**. These positions can be summarized as follows:
>
> [...]
>
> - **in front of an opening brace** ‘{’, **if that brace is a legal continuation of the current statement or expression**,
>
>   [...]

Note that this quote covers only the case with a *single* optional line break. It does not hold for two or more consecutive line breaks, e.g.

```
scala> {
     |   val x = 1
     | 
     |   { val y = 2 }
     | }
```

is valid, and `{ val y = 2 }` is parsed as a separate expression.

I *guess* the motivation was to allow embedded DSL's with syntactic sugar like this:

```
MY_WHILE(x >= 0)
{
  println(x)
  x -= 1
}
```

It would be really strange if one had to enclose each such `MY_WHILE`-statement into an additional pair of round parentheses, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Andrey's answer, it's rare that you write code like this in idiomatic Scala, but, when you do, you should use [`locally`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#locally%5BT%5D(x:T):T):

```
{
  val a = 1
  locally {
    val b = a * 2
    locally {
      val c = b + 4
      c
    }
  }
}
```

This case is exactly why `locally` exists.